# Macro to write dictionary keys to array not working

Tags: excel, dictionary, vba

I am trying to use a dictionary to create array of unique items from a column range

The column cells are text (titles)

I know very little about dictionaries, trying to learn something new

I get an array filled with 1's

Thanks

```
Sub GetUniques()
Dim d As Object, k, a As Variant, c As Variant, i As Long, j As Long, LR As Long

Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
c = Range("D2:D" & LR).Value2

For i = 1 To UBound(c)
d(c(i, 1)) = 1
Next i

ReDim a(1 To d.Count)
j = 1
For Each k In d.keys
   a(j) = k
      j = j + 1
Next k

'See what the first item of the array is
MsgBox a(1)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use collection to create unique items. Here is an example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim Col As New Collection, itm As Variant

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To lRow
            On Error Resume Next
            Col.Add .Range("A" & i).Value, CStr(.Range("A" & i).Value)
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next i
    End With

    For Each itm In Col
        Debug.Print itm
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT**

And if you want to convert that collection to array then you can add this code

```
Dim MyAr() As Variant

ReDim MyAr(0 To (Col.Count - 1))

For i = 1 To Col.Count
    MyAr(i - 1) = Col.Item(i)
Next
```

**Followup from comments**

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim Col As New Collection, itm As Variant

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To lRow
            On Error Resume Next
            Col.Add .Range("A" & i).Value, CStr(.Range("A" & i).Value)
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next i
    End With

    Dim MyAr() As Variant

    ReDim MyAr(0 To (Col.Count - 1))

    For i = 1 To Col.Count
        MyAr(i - 1) = Col.Item(i)
    Next

    ws.Range("K1").Resize(UBound(MyAr), 1) = Application.Transpose(MyAr)
End Sub
```

**Note**: I see that your query is solved but If I was you, I would use the inbuilt `RemoveDuplicates` which is much more faster and shorter than the code above

```
Columns(1).Copy Columns(11)
Columns(11).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
```

Comment: Thank you, I can see that the proper objects are populating the array from the  `debug.print`.  I am would like also to postback the array to the sheet, I am tring `ws.Range("K1:K" & Col.Count).Value = MyAr` but I just get the first object of the array `Col.Count` times

Comment: Yes because you have to transpose it. Updating my answer, One moment

Comment: I have one question though... Why this approach? Why not use RemoveDuplicates which is much more faster and shorter than what you are trying to achieve? See my recent edit. You may have to refresh the page

Comment: I need to use the array in the next step of a process (I wanted the post back to sheet for future reference), if I `RemoveDuplicates ` I would just have to make an array of it so I thought I would try this approach.  As you suggest I am not sure how much I benefited myself with this way of doing it, at the very least I learned a little.  Thank you again

Comment: @Siddharth Rout what is the main consideration you have in preferring Collection over Dictionary in this case.

Comment: Dictionary class is not part of the VBA library, to use Dictionaries in your VBA projects you must either use early binding or late binding. Collections as you can see above are relatively very simple in the above case. And hence I chose collections. Dictionary is more powerful than collections plus it can work in VBS as well but in this particular case, using collection is relatively much simpler. :) @skkakkar